# Python: Assigning query results to nested dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

In a flask project, I am looping through two lists to execute queries.  Items from each list are variables in the SQL statements.  I want the results of each query assigned to a key in the results dict:

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

list1 = [0,1]
list2 = ['criteria1',  'criteria2', 'criteria3']

for item in list1:
    cur.execute(query_one(item))
    foo = cur.fetchall()
    dict1[item] = foo
    for criterion in list2:
        cur.execute(query_two(item, criterion)):
        bar = cur.fetchall()
        dict2[item][criterion] = bar
```

dict1 looks good, but the above gives me KeyError: 0 on dict2.

If I change the last bit to `dict2[criterion] = bar`
Then `dict2` only contains results from the query from `list1[1]` - like so:
`{[result3], [result4]}`

I want  `dict2` to look something like:

```
{0: [results1], [results2], 1: [results3], [results4]}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You misspelled `cur.execute`. You have the wrong kind of quotes in `list2`.

Comment: You never created a dictionary in `dict2[item]`, so you can't assign `dict2[item][criterion]`

Comment: Add `dict2[item] = {}` before the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an empty dictionary in `dict2[item]` so you can assign to its keys.

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

list1 = [0,1]
list2 = ['criteria1',  'criteria2', 'criteria3']

for item in list1:
    cur.execute(query_one(item))
    foo = cur.fetchall()
    dict1[item] = foo 
    dict2[item] = {}
    for criterion in list2:
        cur.execute(query_two(item, criterion)):
        bar = cur.fetchall()
        dict2[item][criterion] = bar
```